# Reading jpeg from file fails with "no such file" but file is clearly there

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I'm running into problems reading jpeg files from the file system and displaying the image in an NSImage. Here's a snippet of code:

```
    NSError *myError;
    NSString *path = @"file:/Users/jpurlia/Documents/Development/Test/1915brsts880804of.jpg";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url
                                         options:0
                                           error:&myError];
    _photoImageView.image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

Running this code generates the following error upon calling dataWithContentsOfURL:
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “1915brsts880804of.jpg” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."
And, additionally:
{Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}

The file does exist, and if I copy the path and paste it into a web browser, the jpeg image is displayed as expected.
I'm guessing this is some kind of permission problem that exists to prevent applications from accessing the file system directly? I had a similar problem when attempting to open files selected from an Open Panel, which turned out to be a problem with running Open/Save Panels from sandboxes, so I turned off sandboxing to get that aspect of my application working.

Does this ring a bell for anyone? I'm kind of baffled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create an `NSURL` using `fileURLWithPath` then you need to provide a path, not a URL. Remove the use of `file:`.

```
NSString *path = @"/Users/jpurlia/Documents/Development/Test/1915brsts880804of.jpg";
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
```

Or you can fix the file URL and use `NSURL URLWithString`. Use `file://` before the absolute file path so you have 3 `/`:

```
NSString *fileURLString = @"file:///Users/jpurlia/Documents/Development/Test/1915brsts880804of.jpg";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fileURLString];
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you! I should have caught that, as my code was originally dealing with URL's and then I switched to paths. Thanks!

Comment: @johnpurlia Glad to help. Please don't forget to indicate that your question has been resolved by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.